# how to create a window in plugin layer starting one thread in onWindowAttached ,when this will be called

Tags: firebreath

```
bool DispatcherPlugin::onWindowAttached(FB::AttachedEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow* window)
```

when this will be called i am starting one thread in the function to dram the frames with open Gl

```
FB::PluginWindowWin* pluginWindowWin = dynamic_cast<FB::PluginWindowWin*>(window);
```

by type casting window to `FB::PluginWindowWin`

How To Create `FB::PluginWindow* window` object so that i will start my thread by  calling one function passing argument as FB::PluginWindow object

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question; could you try to clarify?  Also, NPAPI is pretty much dead on all platforms and so this will only even work on IE....

Comment: How To Get Browser window Handle in Plugin i wanted to play live video frames in Browser window through Plugin , onWindowAttached when it will be triggered in plugin

Comment: What kind of plugin? What browser? Is it configured as a windowed or windowless plugin? it appears you are trying to run on windows, is that correct?

Comment: Also, are you using FireBreath 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using firebreath 2 on chrome browser running on windows ,for both windowed plugin and windoless plugin currently I am using windowed plugin ,actually , from plugin I wanted access browser window , I want to access div elements in html page , I want have the control on htlm page from plugin ,onwindowattached when it will be triggered in plugin , how to attach a window do I have attach from UI html page? Can u help more on this , really I am not sure about the major difference between windowed plugin and windoless less plugin can u share me the link where I can find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a modern version of Chrome then you can't get a plugin window -- you can only use it through nativemessaging which doesn't allow direct access to the browser window.

Your best bet would be to send the data to the page and draw in a canvas with javascript.

PluginWindow is legacy and only works on NPAPI and ActiveX; NPAPI is basically not supported by anything and ActiveX only works in IE these days.

Comment: we have done the same way in current implementation( sending the data to the page and draw in a canvas with javascript). Whenever we pass the large video buffers(10mb frames per second) to the UI layer via extension. The browser memory is increasing more and the memory is not coming down till i refresh the browser. What is the right way to pass video frames to UI layer ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a better way to pass video frames. The native messaging host protocol only allows json data to be passed across, not binary data; you could look into the possibility of detecting and decoding base64 buffers in the background thread, it's possible if you convert it to an ArrayBuffer there it might make a difference